# Making an equation independent of a variable

Tags: trigonometry

sum of all values of $\theta$ for which $\cos^2x+\cos^2(\theta+x)-\cos x\cdot\cos(\theta+x)$  is independent of $x$.

I don't understand what we need to do can someone provide me a hint

Comment: Try and derivate the expression with respect to the $x $ variable. Once you have the derivative, study when it is identically zero uniformly in $x $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2f(x)=2\cos^2\theta+2\cos^2(x+\theta)-2\cos x\cdot\cos(x+\theta)$$

$$=1+\cos2\theta+1+\cos2(x+\theta)-[\cos(2x+\theta)+\cos\theta]$$

To be independent of $x,$  clearly we need $$\cos2(x+\theta)-\cos(2x+\theta)=0$$

Using Prosthaphaeresis Formula,
$$\cos2(x+\theta)-\cos(2x+\theta)=-2\sin\dfrac\theta2\sin\left(2x+\dfrac{3\theta}2\right)$$

So, we need $\sin\dfrac\theta2=0$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\cos^2 x+\cos^2(\theta+x)- \cos x * \cos(\theta)$

Determine  $ \theta$ such that $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$

Answer (score 0):

$f(t,x)=\cos ^2(t+x)-\cos (x) \cos (t+x)+\cos ^2(x)$ is a function of $x$ if its derivative wrt $x$ is identically $0$ for any $x$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\sin (x) \cos (t+x)+\cos (x) \sin (t+x)-2 \sin (t+x) \cos (t+x)-2 \sin (x) \cos (x)$$
which can be reduced to

$(1-2 \cos t) \sin (t+2 x)=0$

$1-2 \cos t =0\to \cos t =\dfrac{1}{2}$

$t=\pm \dfrac{\pi}{3} +2k\pi$

Considering only the values in $[0,\;2\pi]$ the sum should be $2\pi$

hope this helps